# Isolating 9 digit number using Modulo/Divison

Tags: java, integer, division, checksum, modulo

I am trying to develop a small java program that can check to see if a random SIN (Social Insurance Number) is valid. In order for the SIN (9 digits) to be valid, they must sum up to a multiple of 10. This is a valid SIN number I came up with 464-147-464 to test my program. **What I need to do now, is to be able to isolate each digit (using modulo and/or division).** This is what I have come up with so far.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int x1 = 1;
    int x2 = 2;
    int x3 = 3;
    int x4 = 4;
    int x5 = 5;
    int x6 = 6;
    int x7 = 7;
    int x8 = 8;
    int x9 = 9;
    int x0 = 0;


int x1 = 1/100000000; 
int num1 = 1%100000000;

int x2 = 2/10000000;
int num2 = 2%10000000;

int x3 = 3/1000000;
int num3 = 3%1000000;

int x4 = 4/100000;
int num4 = 4%100000;

int x5 = 5/10000;
int num5 = 5%10000;

int x6 = 6/1000;
int num6 = 6%1000;

int x7 = 7/100;
int num7 = 7%100;

int x8 = 8/10;
int num8 = 8%10;

int x9 = 9/1;
int num9 = 9%1;

String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a valid SIN.");
```

Am I on the right track? The whole point is that the user should be able to input any 9 numbers, and if they add up to a multiple of 10 (by using modulo or division) it's good.

Anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this. Your current implementation wont work because using integer arithmetic you get zero for all of the division you are doing.

```
public static boolean validate(int sin) {

    int total = 0;
    for(int i =0;i<9;i++){
        total += sin %10;
        sin = sin/10;
    }
    return total%10==0 && sin ==0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually compile; nor does it check whether `sin` has 9 digits (e.g. `Integer.MAX_VALUE` has 10 digits).

Comment: Yeah you're right but in the question he said "the user should be able to input any 9 numbers, and if they add up to a multiple of 10 (by using modulo or division) it's good." I answered his question i just didnt handle his input. And I fixed my answer so it compiles

Comment: `return total % 10 == 0;`.

Comment: It would probably also be good to check that `sin` has at most 9 digits - since you're dividing by 10 after the last addition, this could just mean you change that last line to `return total%10==0 && sin==0;`  If there's a rule that the beginning digits can't be 0, that should also be considered.

Comment: The leading digit can be 0. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Insurance_Number

Comment: Sure - that is why childofsoong said *at most* 9 digits. That check would allow numbers with leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
public static boolean isValidate(String arg0) {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(arg0.replaceAll("-",""));
               if((num+"").length() != 9 ) return false;
                 int sum = 0;
                    while (0 != num) {
                        sum += (num% 10);
                        num /=  10;
                    }

                return (sum%10==0);
            }
```

USAGE:

```
System.out.println(isValidate("464-144-464")); //returns false
System.out.println(isValidate("460-127-064")); // return true
```

Comment: Do we know for sure that the leading digits can't be 0?

Comment: @childofsoong ty fixed it

Comment: your code returns false using SIN 046 454 286 which is valid. Mine doesn't work with this case either just thought you'd want to know.

Comment: Haha whoops was going off of Wikipedia and didn't read the whole thing. Looks like op isn't correct about how to validate sins. Check out https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Insurance_Number#Temporary_SINs the validation part is different from both of our implementations